# how to classify the tableview month wise and put them in different sections?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, sorting

Iam trying to group the transaction details shown in picture 1 month wise as shown in picture 2 based on the date of each transaction. How do I do it? 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QczOj.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtQwu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use your logic to sort the array and organise it as an dictionary with month as key and array as values in it. Then show it as expandable table view as Rooney said.